# How to add custom currency pattern in culture?

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

I have to add my custom pattern to my custom culture (CultureInfo). There is a list of [all patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) but I didn't find one I need:

```
"n- "
```

So the question is **how to add my custom pattern to culture**?

I know that I can use pattern "n-$" with empty currency symbol, this will make it looks like this, but I can't make my currency symbol empty because I need it in another place.

P.S.: Two cultures is not an option.

**Thank you.**

Comment: Clone existing culture : CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone()  Then make change in cloned culture.

Comment: Please read question again, I mentioned that culture I have to change is already custom.